# Redefinition error while using pointer and an iterator in function overloading

Tags: c++

I am having trouble overloading a constructor so that one version takes an iterator and a pointer the other takes two pointers. I am getting redeclaration error and redefinition error. Here are the declartions:

```
Node(const int*, Node*);

Node(const initializer_list<int>::iterator, Node*);
```

Comment: Need to show more code.

Comment: also compiler please

Comment: The iterator for an `initializer_list<E>` is `const E*`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

Answer (score 0):

A common approach to getting around this sort of overload issue is to make a templated overload; e.g.

```
template <typename Iterator>
Node(Iterator iter, Node *ptr);
```

But this assumes the implementation is generic across these types.